# PushTopic for OpportunityContactRole

Tags: streaming-api, opportunitycontactrole, pushtopic

I'm creating PushTopics for streaming api and have trouble creating one for OpportunityContactRole object.

Executing the following apex code in Developer Console Window

```
PushTopic pushTopic = new PushTopic();
pushTopic.Name = 'test';
pushTopic.Query = 'SELECT Id FROM OpportunityContactRole';
pushTopic.ApiVersion = 50.0;
pushTopic.NotifyForOperationCreate = true;
pushTopic.NotifyForOperationUpdate = true;
pushTopic.NotifyForOperationUndelete = true;
pushTopic.NotifyForOperationDelete = true;
pushTopic.NotifyForFields = 'Referenced';
insert pushTopic;
```

returns the following error

> Line: 10, Column: 1 System.DmlException: Insert failed. First
> exception on row 0; first error: INVALID_FIELD,
> 'OpportunityContactRole' is not supported: [Query]

Similar code with another object (like Opportunity) works.

Is something different with OpportunityContactRole here?

Answer (score 1):

According to [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_streaming.meta/api_streaming/supported_soql.htm) only custom objects and a subset of standard objects (see below) support PushTopic queries:

```
Account
Campaign
Case
Contact
ContractLineItem
Entitlement
Lead
LiveChatTranscript
Opportunity
Quote
QuoteLineItem
ServiceAppointment
ServiceContract
Task
WorkOrder
WorkOrderLineItem
```